# Azure, Error 403 - Forbidden: Client Certificate Required

Tags: asp.net-core, ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying create a "App Service" in Azure and in the Setting area set the "Custom Domain" and "TLS/SSL setting" (ssl binding: SNI SSL). Then I put a html file via ftp and got error this below.

> Error 403 - Forbidden: Client Certificate Required.
>
> The web app you have attempted to reach requires a client certificate
> and does not accept any requests without one.

this error above was produced in Chrome and Firefox but in Opera, it just works fine. I try in MS Edge always show pop-up confirm notification. I think chrome and firefox don't recognize the certification, do they ? [image: MS Edge popup]

Well, I thought that because html file need some modification for https setting.
Then, I tried using standard project from VS 2017 and published it, I still get same error in chrome & firrefox but again opera works fine and MS Edge needs confirm certificate pop up.

Any suggestion, how to solve this browser error ?
I think this an easy setting but it become so headache.

Comment: Have you imported the certificate to your browser(Chrome and Firefox) ? And could you please try to enable "HTTPS Only" in the left navigation(TLS/SSL settings --> HTTPS Only) on your Azure portal ? After enable "HTTPS Only", Opera may be also pop up a notification to ask for certificate.

Comment: actually, I'm agree with you and I tried to import/export from Opera browser to others browser but 1 thing that opera doesn't provide is the export KEY: No.

Answer (score 6):

Eventually, I got the answer and it works well
[image: incoming client certification: disabled]

Comment: 1. I have reviewed the issue you described and based on my findings, you need to turn off your incoming client certificates settings for your App Service from Azure portal to Resolve this issue.
I could see that the error that you are facing due to your Incoming client certificates setting is turned on. Client certificates allows for your app to request a certificate for incoming requests. Only clients that have a valid certificate will be able to reach your app. If you turned Incoming client certificates setting off then your client browser does not face this kind of error.

Comment: 2. For securely accessing your App Services you already have SSL bindings for the custom domain added to the App Service. I have checked at our end Binding & SSL Configuration and everything seems alright. Just to the required changes suggested above and share with us your findings
You will find this setting in this path : Azure Portal >> App Service >> TLS/SSL Settings >> Incoming client certificates >> Click “Off”

Comment: 2 above comment are replies from azure support

Comment: Today I faced the same issue. When I checked the setting is already Off. Don't know why it is asking for a client certificate. Then I changed the setting to ON and back to OFF. This resolve my issue.

Answer (score 5):

In the new Azure they moved this option to

In Settings section : Configuration -> General Setting

[image]