# Users complaining of a "Select a certificate" popup on my web sites

Tags: ssl, https, azure-web-app-service, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

I have a couple websites launched in Azure. The URLs end with `.azurewebsites.net` which is fine with me. But recently, we've received multiple complaints that when the users visit these sites, they receive a popup in their browsers similar to the following:

[image]

I don't know anything about https or SSL certificates. My question is:

1. Why did this start happening recently? I've had my websites up for a long time and now we're getting this?
2. Can I update my websites so that users don't receive this popup anymore? If so, how?

Thank you.

Comment: This happens if you have enabled authentication with client certificates.

Comment: As the website developer, can I disable this? Or is this something the users have to disable on their machines? Thank you.

Comment: This is a setting for the web server, not on the client. It is probably enabled accidentally, maybe by assuming that it meant something different. I'm not familiar with the options offered to you but the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58075701/azure-error-403-forbidden-client-certificate-required) might steer you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to recieve the  popup , you can disable the setting in Azure Portal
Go to Azure Portal =>Your Web App =>Configuration =>General Settings

- Select `Optional` under Client certificate mode

[image]

**OR**

- If you don't want to disable , You can provide the windows sign-in as authentication

[image]